# Akka: How to combine OneForOneStrategy and AllForOneStrategy

Tags: scala, akka-supervision

If I define the supervisor strategy for an actor in Scala, how can I use both the `OneForOneStrategy` and the `AllForOneStrategy`? Is there a simple way to combine them or do I have to define a custom `SupervisorStrategy`?
Here is an example:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _: NullPointerException  => Restart
    case _: FileNotFoundException => Restart // here I want to restart all children
    case _: Exception             => Escalate
  }
}
```

If I have to write my own supervisor strategy, how can I do this? I found no example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define a custom supervisor strategy. For your specific use case, the following custom strategy would work:

```
package akka.actor

import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class CustomStrategy(
  maxNrOfRetries:              Int      = -1,
  withinTimeRange:             Duration = Duration.Inf,
  override val loggingEnabled: Boolean  = true)(val decider: SupervisorStrategy.Decider)
  extends SupervisorStrategy {

  import SupervisorStrategy._

  private val retriesWindow = (maxNrOfRetriesOption(maxNrOfRetries), withinTimeRangeOption(withinTimeRange).map(_.toMillis.toInt))

  def handleChildTerminated(context: ActorContext, child: ActorRef, children: Iterable[ActorRef]): Unit = ()

  def processFailure(context: ActorContext, restart: Boolean, child: ActorRef, cause: Throwable, stats: ChildRestartStats, children: Iterable[ChildRestartStats]): Unit = {
    if (cause.isInstanceOf[FileNotFoundException]) {
      // behave like AllForOneStrategy
      if (children.nonEmpty) {
        if (restart && children.forall(_.requestRestartPermission(retriesWindow)))
          children foreach (crs ⇒ restartChild(crs.child, cause, suspendFirst = (crs.child != child)))
        else
          for (c ← children) context.stop(c.child)
      }
    } else {
      // behave like OneForOneStrategy
      if (restart && stats.requestRestartPermission(retriesWindow))
        restartChild(child, cause, suspendFirst = false)
      else
        context.stop(child)
    }
  }
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/chunjef/05c5acf3b940eb1e09487dfc82eee328) is a gist that tests the above strategy. The spec creates a supervisor that uses `CustomStrategy` and it creates two children. When one child throws a `NullPointerException`, only that child is restarted; when a child throws a `FileNotFoundException`, both children are restarted.

A few notes about the custom strategy:

- It extends [`SupervisorStrategy`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/SupervisorStrategy.html) and is modeled after the existing strategies defined [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/FaultHandling.scala).
- It is defined inside the `akka.actor` package to have access to the package-private members there.
- [`processFailure`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/SupervisorStrategy.html#processFailure(context:akka.actor.ActorContext,restart:Boolean,child:akka.actor.ActorRef,cause:Throwable,stats:akka.actor.ChildRestartStats,children:Iterable[akka.actor.ChildRestartStats]):Unit), one of the methods that must be overridden in classes that extend `SupervisorStrategy`, is called on [`Restart`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/FaultHandling.scala#L304) and [`Stop`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/FaultHandling.scala#L308), so for your scenario, we define the custom behavior there.

Comment: I am suprised, that it has to be defined inside the `akk.actor`. To make it more general one could also override the OneForOneStartegy and add a `RestartAll` and a `StopAll` decider directive, right?

Comment: Overriding the `OneForOneStrategy` should be avoided, because it is a case class. Extending the `Decider` type is also not possible, because it is sealed and the specs (`Resume`, `Restart`, ...) are case objects (so I can also not extend `Restart` for creating `RestartAll`). To make the example more general it is necessary to write a complete new SupervisorStrategy class.